# Extract value from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, arrays, string, dictionary, jupyter-notebook

The final result of a Python code is like this:

```
print(results)
{'test': 1.023, 'solution': 4.025, 'best_value': -0.041}
```

If I run this

```
value_1, value2, value3 = results
print(value3)
```

I get

```
best_value
```

but I want to extract the numerical values, in this case:

```
1.023
4.025
-0.041
```

How can I extract numeric values with code?

Comment: Did you mean to do something like `results['test'], results['solution'], results['best_value']`?

Answer (score 1):

Unpacking values will work for this case, but it would fail if the dictionary is in another order (such as `{'best_value': -0.041', test': 1.023, 'solution': 4.025}`.

This is a more robust way of doing it:

```py
value_1, value2, value3 = results["test"], results["solution"], results["best_value"]
```

or, more explicitly:

```py
value_1 = results["test"], 
value_2 = results["solution"]
value_3 = results["best_value"]
```